# Animating the layout to 50% and 30% of screen size and vice-versa in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, imageview, onclicklistener

I had a layout and imageview. On Imageview click i want to move the layout to move down till 30% of screen. then clicking on imageview i want to move the layout to move up till 50% of screen. Remember imageview is attached with the layout i am animating?

any help will be appreciated
thanks!

Comment: please post your layout xml